# Add Columns to Rubymotion Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, rubymotion, ipad

I'm using Rubymotion to create a basic iPad App. Is there a way to directly add columns to  a UITableView, I found an add column using objective-c at this link

http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html

This code creates a grid in the cell using the addColumn method.

How can I use this method in RubyMotion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subclass UITableViewCell as they do:

```
def MyTableCell < UITableViewCell 
  def addColumn(position)
    # Add their example code here
  end
  # Etc
end
```

...I'm not going to do it for you, but you get the idea. Just convert Obj-C to RubyMotion. They give you a pretty complete example there.

If you're targeting iOS 6+, there is a new object called UICollectionView which could also give you the capability you're looking to create:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html